Robust Variance Estimation or Cluster Wild Bootstrapping on a multivariate meta-analysis
Cliffnotes
Can I use RVE or cluster wild bootstrapping in meta-analytic models that are not
meta-regression?
Question
I am conducting a three-level meta-analysis looking at the effects of a particular psychotherapy intervention (vs. comparator) on a number of psychiatric symptom domains. Please see model below:
full.model <- rma.mv(yi = es,  
                     V = var, 
                     slab = study,
                     data = depression,
                     random = ~ 1 | study/es.id, 
                     test = "t", 
                     method = "REML")

The effect sizes in this case are nested within study clusters. I know these effects to be correlated, because they are all drawn from the same sample, and I want to account for this dependency by using RVE and imputing a constant correlation covariance matrix as below:
rho <- 0.7
V.7 <- with(depression, 
            impute_covariance_matrix(vi = var,
                                     cluster = study,
                                     r = rho))

che.model.7 <- rma.mv(yi = es,
                V = V.7,
                random = ~ 1 | study/es.id,
                data = depression,
                sparse = TRUE)

I have then been using the clubSandwich package to calculate cluster robust inferential statistics, e.g., SEs, Sattherwaithe-df-adjusted  95% CIs and p-values. All the literature I am reading gives me the impression that this can only be done on meta-regression models and I fear that my application may be inappropriate for reasons I currently do not understand. Moreover, because my sample size is quite small, 13 studies and 26 effects, I am worried that this form of RVE might inflate Type I error resulting in overly conservative stats.
I wanted to then use wildmeta to estimate these dependencies using cluster wild bootstrapping but I have not been able to use the package to produce estimates, which again makes me concerned that this is only applicable to meta-regression models with more than one coefficient.
Please help me to understand accounting for dependencies in non-regression multivariate meta-analysis model.s

You might get better answers on the mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//

Cluster robust inference methods can most certainly be used for models without moderators. Whether RVE 'works' in your case (i.e., the Type I error rate is controlled / the coverage of confidence intervals is nominal) is impossible to say in general, but simulation results (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.5 and https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.1070) suggest that RVE works even with a smaller number of studies when estimating the average effect size.

My sincerest thanks, Wolfgang. Am I correct that using:
robust.full.model <- robust(full.model, cluster = study, clubSandwich = TRUE)
predict(robust.full.model)
Would provide me cluster robust prediction intervals?

Yes, sort of. RVE does not affect the estimates of the variance components, only the estimated SE of the predicted value. The former however are what distinguishes the CI from the PI. So yes, you will get a PI that is based on RVE, but if the model is misspecified, then the variance components may be biased, which then impacts the PI.
